# SVGs export adding pixels in preview and browser

Tags: svg, export, sketch-app, subpixel-rendering

Hopefully some simple solution to this, but basically when I export an icon create in sketch it basically adds a pixel. Is this an export problem or a rendering issue in chrome for example? (or both).

**Here's a screenshot of what's being exported:**

[image]

As you can see it all aligns to the pixel grid etc.

**Here is what I see in preview:**

[image]

As you can see it's distinctly broken. I guess perhaps the arrow head is broken because the tip falls on a half pixel? But I can't explain the issue with the horizontal line at the top doubling in height! Please help!

Comment: That might just be a preview rendering error. What happens when you output it as a raster image, or as an SVG and view it in a browser?  Previews are just previews . . . after all.

Comment: same problem in the browser. I've exported it from illustrator and it's seemingly fine so must be a sketch issue

Comment: Have you tried exporting to SVG? Check the generated SVG code and see if the dimensions are leaking off above the grid (if you find some really strange floating point decimals instead of exact integer values).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the old export option (File>Export>Export As). This way you can define how many decimal places the SVG is rounded to. Try '2'. This can tidy things up a bit.

[image].

Comment: Note that the smaller the viewBox the more decimals may be required.